# Confuse about the Firebase A/B user group and Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase-analytics, firebase-ab-testing

We used Firebase A/B a lot and we noticed that sometimes users may not get their remote config values due to various reasons(eg:network error, slow network),If we upload key event that we want to use in A/B testing at this time, Will the event include in A/B analytics? Which group will the event belong?

We hope the event can be include in the right group only when the user get the right A/B remote config value.

An example scene:

1.I Create a A/B  Test named "Login UI" and use remote config "new_login_ui" to test a new login UI.

new_login_ui: default value is "":old UI,  GROUP A:"false":old UI, GROUP B:"true":new UI

2.I use an event "login_success" as the test goal metric.

3.A user entered my app but get "new_login_ui"'s default value "", so app give the user old UI, after user login success, I upload the "login_success" event.

4.Next time user entered my app, I found user get "new_login_ui" value "true", so the user is grouped to GROUP B.

Then the confuse occur, will the event "login_success" with old UI behavior included in GROUP B which is the new UI group?

If it's true, then the A/B result is ruined because the login_success is belong to old UI group.

Answer (score 0):

If the app receives the default parameter value, probably, the user is not yet included in the experiment. If the user satisfies all the targeting conditions and it calls fetch > activate or fetchAndActivate method on Remote Config, you should see a conditional user property (e.g. firebase_exp_id, id being the experiment number) in the analytics verbose logs. To validate your implementation, you may enable the verbose logging and debug mode in your app, then use the [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) console.

Once the conditional user property is set, the SDK will start to track the events that will be logged by the user.

You may use the [Remote Config loading strategy 2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/loading#strategy_2_activate_behind_loading_screen) if you're loading Remote Config values from experiment. This will give A/B Testing additional time as the user is placed into an experiment and the experimental values are applied.